# Organising Weeks and Days

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am making an MVC application that requires daily readings which are organised into weeks, which are in turn organised into years. I have a week entity, and a day entity, which are tables of weeks and days respectively. Is there any way I can link the days to a `WeekNo` but not have `WeekNo` or `DayNo` as the primary keys?

For example, there'd be 5 working days in week 1:

```
WeekNo = 1, DayNo = 1
WeekNo = 1, DayNo = 2
WeekNo = 1, DayNo = 3
WeekNo = 1, DayNo = 4
WeekNo = 1, DayNo = 5
```

Then when Week 2 comes along:

```
WeekNo = 1, DayNo = 1
```

But then there is a duplicate of Day 1.

I am having a similar problem with the weeks in a year, that when the next year comes along and it's back to Week 1, there's a duplicate in weeks. But if I can get past this, maybe I would be able figure that out too.

How would I go about referencing these to each other?

`Day` model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Utility.Models
{
    public class Day
    {
        public int DayID { get; set; }
        public int WeekNo { get; set; }
        public int DayNo { get; set; }
        public string DayofWeek { get; set; }
        public float Reading1 { get; set; }
        public float Reading2 { get; set; }
        //etc

        public virtual Week Week { get; set; }

    }
}
```

`Week` model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Utility.Models
{
    public class Week
    {
        public int WeekID { get; set; }
        public int WeekNo { get; set; }
        public int YearID { get; set; }

        public virtual Year Year { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Day> Days { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `WeekNo` property anywhere..

Comment: Oh sorry, I have been using a lot of different code messing around with this. I have edited the code and it should be the relevant code now.

Comment: How about many to many? creating another Entity called WeekDay, Day has many WeekDays, Week has many WeekDays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about many to many relationship?

```
public class Day
{
    public int DayID { get; set; }
    public int DayNo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WeekDay> WeekDays { get; set; }
}
public class Week
{
    public int WeekID { get; set; }
    public int WeekNo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WeekDay> WeekDays { get; set; }
}
public class WeekDay
{
    public int WeekDayID { get; set; }
    public int DayID { get; set; }
    public virtual Day Day { get; set; }
    public int WeekID { get; set; }
    public virtual Week Week { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thank you :) So when I'm making the controller, and click "New Scaffolded Item", will WeekDay be the model I reference?

Comment: If your view is about to do CRUD operation on a certain `Week` that will process days collection, I think it should be `Week`.

Comment: Yeah CRUD. Okay, thank you again, I'll try it out and see how I get on. :)

Comment: Would you mind me asking you another question about the initializer I'm making? I'll add another answer to show you.

Comment: How about put it in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), so others can help too..

Comment: That's true. I just thought I'd put it here while you were. But yeah you're right. I put the answer in here before seeing your comment any way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57932/discussion-between-yuliam-chandra-and-calturk).