# Updating a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I am making an MVC application that does daily readings input by the user and stores the data in a table. I have the entities `Year`, `Week` and `Day`, all tables of their name. I am having some trouble with the `Week` and `Day`s though.

`Week` Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Utility2.Models
{
    public class Week
    {
        public int WeekID { get; set; }
        public int WeekNo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<WeekDay> WeekDays { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Day` Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Utility2.Models
{
    public class Day
    {
        public int DayID { get; set; }
        public int DayNo { get; set; }
        public float Reading1 { get; set; }
        public float Reading2 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<WeekDay> WeekDays { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And lastly, the `WeekDay` Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Utility2.Models
{
    public class WeekDay
    {
        public int WeekDayID { get; set; }

        public int DayID { get; set; }
        public virtual Day Day { get; set; }

        public int WeekID { get; set; }
        public virtual Week Week { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I create a day, how do I have it so the user can pick from the available weeks and then the day would be linked to that week.

For example, if it was Monday on Week 3, the user would create Week 3, then they would get their readings, go to create a day and have a drop down menu maybe of the available weeks, select 3, input the readings, and then that day is linked to that week.

Comment: Is your question about, how to build the Day View or what?

Comment: Not really. Do I need to put anything in the controller to do this or how do I put something in the create page that gives to user an option to select the week when creating a day. At the moment, the only boxes in the create page are for `DayNo`, `Reading1` and `Reading2`

Comment: You have to put an IEnumerable to your ViewBag conatining the weeks you want to display in your Day View

Comment: How do I go about that? Would that update `WeekDay` and have the week and day linked? Sorry, I am only learning MVC, I should have said.

Comment: First of all, do you really need a many to many relationship? Can a Day really be related to more than one week?

Comment: Well I thought I didn't but then I came across a problem with duplicates and I asked on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930378/organising-weeks-and-days) and was advised to use a many to many relationship.

Comment: OK, if you need the many to many relationship, then I would add another property to your Day Model, which is not mapped (`NotMapped`-Attribute if you are using EF) to your database, which represents a WeekID. Then in your view add a DropDownListFor for the week to be selected. The source for the DropDownList needs to be provided as a IEnumerable you pass to your View via ViewBag. When saving the new Day, you could then use the selected WeekId and the Id of the new Day to create a new entry in the WeekDay Table. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I thought I'd need something else in there, but did not know about `NotMapped`. I pretty much understand you and the theory, might have to google a way to code it :P Thank you for your help :)

Comment: How would you go about creating the new WeekDay table from there do you know?